# Is it possible to change package name on android project in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, package

the package name for my project is `org.consulting.keno`, could I change it somehow to something like `org.consulting.keno2`?

The problem is that I submitted an app to the google store as free and want to change it to charge money. The google store said I would have to remove the old one and re-submit a new apx file. But I get a error saying conflicting package name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the package explorer, right click on the package and chose

```
Refactor > Rename
```

Type in the new name and you are done.

Comment: That should do it, but I wonder if you unpublish the Free app from the Android Market first, then submit the paid version using the same package name if it will still give the "conflicting package name" error. This might be worth trying if you don't need both the free and paid version active at the same time.

Comment: First I thought Ted wanted to provide both versions - but now that you mention it, yes, just removing the old app from the market should do it :)

Comment: Hi,
Was I tried unpubliching and freeing it, did not work,
I need some help, this is what I did
1. Selected the java browsing perspective.
2. Selected my project on left hand side
3. In middle of screen under packages, I selected my package to rename.
4. Right clicked on it, did not have refractor.
5. Clicked on Rename from the refracter menu, nothing happen?

Answer (score 19):

I would like to complete Mef's answer. In a lot of cases this solution is not enough, cause not all the package name references in the manifest are changed and some other issues may appear. The three step solution is as below:

1. Right click on the package name then Refract > Rename.
2. Right click on the project name Android tools > Rename Application Package.
3. Manually set the package names of the Manifest that have not been changed by the previous steps.

Looks like it does not need any cleaning or resetting of the IDE (I am using Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the package name and press F2. Rename to what you want. Then open the gen folder then rename the package there as well.

And don't forget to change the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml file as well