# Map not being displayed after refactoring to change the name of the project and package

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm close to finish my first app so I change its name and the corresponding packages. To do so, I used the Android Tools from Eclipse and everything works after one or two attemps (there where a couple of things that I had to change manually), but in general, following the comments from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251942/is-it-possible-to-change-package-name-on-android-project-in-eclipse/9244075#9244075), there were not further problems. Except for the Google Maps. Now they are not being displayed anymore and I'm getting the following error:

```
Google Maps Android API(12251): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I know that there is no connection problem because I'm getting other kind of info from the internet and because the following sentence is true:

```
int availabilityCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
if(availabilityCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
```

The first thing that I did was to go to the Google API and change the package name in the place where you generate the key to make it match the new one. That didn't work, so I deleted the key and created a new one. I pasted the new API key in the Android Manifest but it is not working. Any clues? I'm missing any steps?

In the manifest I still have the needed permissions set, like

```
<permission
    android:name="com.alvarosantisteban.pathos.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

etc.

Comment: After you change API key in manifest, try "Clear data" in your application or re-install

Comment: @android_hungry Is "clear data" the same thing as "clean" the project?

Comment: @AlvaroSantistebean No, usually on the device you have to go to settings-->apps-->your app--> clear data
You can do the same on emulator

Comment: Sometimes the update following a change at Google API console is sloooooow.

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban try to regenerate the API keys and uninstall the app from device ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609772/google-places-shows-blank/18611852#18611852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was a combination of the three things commented here:

- That the api key was not valid anymore (but when I posted the question, I already had that done, as I mentioned on it)
- But specially that I had to clean the data. I actually deleted the app, because, thanks to the help of android_hungry I went to check my apps and saw that my app appeared two times, one with the maps workings and the other one, the one that is on my desktop as a shortcut, not.
- Additionally, it might have happened what silver_man mentioned, I'm not sure.

Thanks to all for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new api key, as the fingerprint is made from your package name. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=es#obtaining_an_api_key